# I am trying to update with multiple id's in laravel

Tags: laravel, updates

```
Customer::where('id'=>[5,6,7])->update(['name' => "Ashutosh"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
Customer::whereIn('id', [5,6,7])->update(['name' => "Ashutosh"]);
```

You can found in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) about `whereIn`.